# How to improve Style Dictionary configuration to generate a proper android file output?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, style-dictionary, figma-plugin, design-tokens

I am using Figma Design Token plugin for generating android code in output with all design tokens.
The current config.json file of Style Dictionary seems not to work as expected.

Config.json file:

```
{
  "source": [
    "tokens/**/*.json"
  ],
  "platforms": {
    "android": {
      "transformGroup": "android",
      "buildPath": "build/android/",
      "files": [
        {
          "destination": "font_dimens.xml",
          "format": "android/fontDimens"
        },
        {
          "destination": "colors.xml",
          "format": "android/colors"
        }
      ]
    },
    "compose": {
      "transformGroup": "compose",
      "buildPath": "build/compose/",
      "files": [
        {
          "destination": "StyleDictionaryColor.kt",
          "format": "compose/object",
          "className": "StyleDictionaryColor",
          "packageName": "StyleDictionaryColor",
          "filter": {
            "original": {
              "type": "color"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "destination": "StyleDictionarySize.kt",
          "format": "compose/object",
          "className": "StyleDictionarySize",
          "packageName": "StyleDictionarySize",
          "type": "float",
          "filter": {
            "original": {
              "type": "spacing"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Design token JSON file (from Figma):

```
{
  "universal": {
    "$spacing-xxx-compact": {
      "value": "2px",
      "type": "spacing"
    },
    "$spacing-xx-compact": {
      "value": "4px",
      "type": "spacing"
    },
    "$spacing-x-compact": {
      "value": "8px",
      "type": "spacing"
    },
    "$spacing-compact": {
      "value": "12px",
      "type": "spacing"
    },
    "$spacing-default": {
      "value": "160px",
      "type": "spacing"
    },
    "$spacing-spacious": {
      "value": "24px",
      "type": "spacing"
    },
    "$spacing-x-spacious": {
      "value": "32px",
      "type": "spacing"
    },
    "$spacing-xx-spacious": {
      "value": "40px",
      "type": "spacing"
    },
    "$spacing-xxx-spacious": {
      "value": "64px",
      "type": "spacing"
    },
    "$sizing-x-small": {
      "value": "16px",
      "type": "sizing"
    },
    "$sizing-small": {
      "value": "24px",
      "type": "sizing"
    },
    "$sizing-medium": {
      "value": "32px",
      "type": "sizing"
    },
    "$sizing-large": {
      "value": "40px",
      "type": "sizing"
    },
    "$sizing-x-large": {
      "value": "56px",
      "type": "sizing"
    },
    "$sizing-xx-large": {
      "value": "64px",
      "type": "sizing"
    },
    "$sizing-xxx-large": {
      "value": "80px",
      "type": "sizing"
    },
    "$sizing-xxxx-large": {
      "value": "120px",
      "type": "sizing"
    },
    "$sizing-xxxxx-large": {
      "value": "480px",
      "type": "sizing"
    },
    "$font-family-default": {
      "value": "Inter",
      "type": "fontFamilies"
    },
    "$color-white": {
      "value": "#FFFFFF",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-grey50": {
      "value": "#F6F6F6",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-grey100": {
      "value": "#ededee",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-grey200": {
      "value": "#dcdcde",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-grey300": {
      "value": "#b9babd",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-grey400": {
      "value": "#73757a",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-grey500": {
      "value": "#505259",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-grey600": {
      "value": "#44464C",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-grey700": {
      "value": "#34353A",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-grey800": {
      "value": "#28292D",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-grey900": {
      "value": "#101012",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-primary900": {
      "value": "#032715",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-primary800": {
      "value": "#054023",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-primary700": {
      "value": "#075a31",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-primary600": {
      "value": "#09733e",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-primary500": {
      "value": "#0b8c4c",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-primary400": {
      "value": "#37a16c",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-primary300": {
      "value": "#63b58c",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-primary200": {
      "value": "#8fcaad",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-primary100": {
      "value": "#bbdfcd",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-primary50": {
      "value": "#e7f4ed",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-secondary900": {
      "value": "#0f284e",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-secondary800": {
      "value": "#163a6f",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-secondary700": {
      "value": "#1c4b90",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-secondary600": {
      "value": "#2562bd",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-secondary500": {
      "value": "#2b73de",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-secondary400": {
      "value": "#558fe5",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-secondary300": {
      "value": "#aac7f2",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-secondary200": {
      "value": "#d5e3f8",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-secondary100": {
      "value": "#e9f1fb",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-yellow900": {
      "value": "#584618",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-yellow800": {
      "value": "#7e6523",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-yellow700": {
      "value": "#b08d30",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-yellow600": {
      "value": "#e3b53e",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-yellow500": {
      "value": "#fcc945",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-yellow400": {
      "value": "#fdd46a",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-yellow300": {
      "value": "#fee9b5",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-yellow200": {
      "value": "#fef4da",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-yellow100": {
      "value": "#fef9ec",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-orange900": {
      "value": "#613500",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-orange800": {
      "value": "#9d5600",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-orange700": {
      "value": "#c26a00",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-orange600": {
      "value": "#da7800",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-orange500": {
      "value": "#f28500",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-orange400": {
      "value": "#f59d33",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-orange300": {
      "value": "#face99",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-orange200": {
      "value": "#fce7cc",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-orange100": {
      "value": "#fdf2e5",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-red900": {
      "value": "#71160f",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-red800": {
      "value": "#871a11",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-red700": {
      "value": "#9e1e14",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-red600": {
      "value": "#b42217",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-red500": {
      "value": "#e12b1d",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-red400": {
      "value": "#e7554a",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-red300": {
      "value": "#f3aaa5",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-red200": {
      "value": "#f9d5d2",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-red100": {
      "value": "#fce9e8",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$font-size-50": {
      "value": "10px",
      "type": "fontSizes"
    },
    "$font-size-75": {
      "value": "12px",
      "type": "fontSizes"
    },
    "$font-size-100": {
      "value": "14px",
      "type": "fontSizes"
    },
    "$font-size-200": {
      "value": "16px",
      "type": "fontSizes"
    },
    "$font-size-300": {
      "value": "18px",
      "type": "fontSizes"
    },
    "$font-size-400": {
      "value": "24px",
      "type": "fontSizes"
    },
    "$font-size-500": {
      "value": "32px",
      "type": "fontSizes"
    },
    "$font-size-600": {
      "value": "42px",
      "type": "fontSizes"
    },
    "$line-height-50": {
      "value": "16px",
      "type": "lineHeights"
    },
    "$line-height-75": {
      "value": "20px",
      "type": "lineHeights"
    },
    "$line-height-100": {
      "value": "22px",
      "type": "lineHeights"
    },
    "$line-height-200": {
      "value": "24px",
      "type": "lineHeights"
    },
    "$line-height-300": {
      "value": "26px",
      "type": "lineHeights"
    },
    "$line-height-400": {
      "value": "32px",
      "type": "lineHeights"
    },
    "$line-height-500": {
      "value": "46px",
      "type": "lineHeights"
    },
    "$line-height-600": {
      "value": "56px",
      "type": "lineHeights"
    },
    "$font-weight-regular": {
      "value": "400",
      "type": "fontWeights"
    },
    "$font-weight-medium": {
      "value": "500",
      "type": "fontWeights"
    },
    "$font-weight-semibold": {
      "value": "600",
      "type": "fontWeights"
    },
    "$letter-spacing-compact": {
      "value": "-0.1px",
      "type": "letterSpacing"
    },
    "$letter-spacing-default": {
      "value": "0px",
      "type": "letterSpacing"
    },
    "$letter-spacing-spacious": {
      "value": "0.3px",
      "type": "letterSpacing"
    },
    "$letter-spacing-x-spacious": {
      "value": "0.5px",
      "type": "letterSpacing"
    },
    "$text-decoration-default": {
      "value": "none",
      "type": "textDecoration"
    },
    "$text-decoration-link": {
      "value": "underline",
      "type": "textDecoration"
    },
    "$text-decoration-crossed": {
      "value": "line-through",
      "type": "textDecoration"
    },
    "$border-radius-x-small": {
      "value": "4px",
      "type": "borderRadius"
    },
    "$border-radius-small": {
      "value": "8px",
      "type": "borderRadius"
    },
    "$border-radius-medium": {
      "value": "12px",
      "type": "borderRadius"
    },
    "$border-radius-large": {
      "value": "16px",
      "type": "borderRadius"
    },
    "$border-radius-x-large": {
      "value": "20px",
      "type": "borderRadius"
    },
    "$border-radius-xx-large": {
      "value": "24px",
      "type": "borderRadius"
    },
    "$border-radius-round": {
      "value": "999px",
      "type": "borderRadius"
    },
    "$border-width-medium": {
      "value": "1px",
      "type": "borderWidth"
    },
    "$border-width-large": {
      "value": "2px",
      "type": "borderWidth"
    },
    "$shadow-primary-active": {
      "value": {
        "x": "0",
        "y": "8px",
        "blur": "16px",
        "spread": "0",
        "color": "rgba(16,16,18,0.08)",
        "type": "dropShadow"
      },
      "type": "boxShadow"
    },
    "$shadow-primary-hover": {
      "value": {
        "x": "0",
        "y": "16px",
        "blur": "24px",
        "spread": "0",
        "color": "rgba(16,16,18,0.08)",
        "type": "dropShadow"
      },
      "type": "boxShadow"
    },
    "$shadow-primary-pressed": {
      "value": {
        "x": "0",
        "y": "2px",
        "blur": "8px",
        "spread": "0",
        "color": "rgba(16,16,18,0.08)",
        "type": "dropShadow"
      },
      "type": "boxShadow"
    },
    "$opacity-50": {
      "value": "0.5",
      "type": "opacity"
    }
  },
  "semantic": {
    "$typography-headline1": {
      "value": {
        "fontFamily": "{$font-family-default}",
        "fontWeight": "{$font-weight-medium}",
        "fontSize": "{$font-size-600}",
        "lineHeight": "{$line-height-600}",
        "letterSpacing": "{$letter-spacing-default}"
      },
      "type": "typography"
    },
    "$typography-headline2": {
      "value": {
        "fontFamily": "{$font-family-default}",
        "fontWeight": "{$font-weight-medium}",
        "lineHeight": "{$line-height-500}",
        "fontSize": "{$font-size-500}",
        "letterSpacing": "{$letter-spacing-default}"
      },
      "type": "typography"
    },
    "$typography-title1": {
      "value": {
        "fontFamily": "{$font-family-default}",
        "fontWeight": "{$font-weight-semibold}",
        "lineHeight": "{$line-height-400}",
        "fontSize": "{$font-size-400}",
        "letterSpacing": "{$letter-spacing-default}"
      },
      "type": "typography"
    },
    "$typography-title2": {
      "value": {
        "fontFamily": "{$font-family-default}",
        "fontWeight": "{$font-weight-semibold}",
        "lineHeight": "{$line-height-300}",
        "fontSize": "{$font-size-300}",
        "letterSpacing": "{$letter-spacing-default}"
      },
      "type": "typography"
    },
    "$typography-body-large-low-emphasis": {
      "value": {
        "fontFamily": "{$font-family-default}",
        "fontWeight": "{$font-weight-regular}",
        "lineHeight": "{$line-height-200}",
        "fontSize": "{$font-size-200}",
        "letterSpacing": "{$letter-spacing-default}"
      },
      "type": "typography"
    },
    "$typography-body-large-medium-emphasis": {
      "value": {
        "fontFamily": "{$font-family-default}",
        "fontWeight": "{$font-weight-medium}",
        "lineHeight": "{$line-height-200}",
        "fontSize": "{$font-size-200}",
        "letterSpacing": "{$letter-spacing-default}"
      },
      "type": "typography"
    },
    "$typography-body-large-high-emphasis": {
      "value": {
        "fontFamily": "{$font-family-default}",
        "fontWeight": "{$font-weight-semibold}",
        "lineHeight": "{$line-height-200}",
        "fontSize": "{$font-size-200}",
        "letterSpacing": "{$letter-spacing-default}"
      },
      "type": "typography"
    },
    "$typography-body-large-link": {
      "value": {
        "fontFamily": "{$font-family-default}",
        "fontWeight": "{$font-weight-semibold}",
        "lineHeight": "{$line-height-200}",
        "fontSize": "{$font-size-200}",
        "letterSpacing": "{$letter-spacing-default}",
        "textDecoration": "{$text-decoration-link}"
      },
      "type": "typography"
    },
    "$typography-body-medium-low-emphasis": {
      "value": {
        "fontFamily": "{$font-family-default}",
        "fontWeight": "{$font-weight-regular}",
        "lineHeight": "{$line-height-100}",
        "fontSize": "{$font-size-100}",
        "letterSpacing": "{$letter-spacing-default}"
      },
      "type": "typography"
    },
    "$typography-body-medium-medium-emphasis": {
      "value": {
        "fontFamily": "{$font-family-default}",
        "fontWeight": "{$font-weight-medium}",
        "lineHeight": "{$line-height-100}",
        "fontSize": "{$font-size-100}",
        "letterSpacing": "{$letter-spacing-default}"
      },
      "type": "typography"
    },
    "$typography-body-medium-high-emphasis": {
      "value": {
        "fontFamily": "{$font-family-default}",
        "fontWeight": "{$font-weight-semibold}",
        "lineHeight": "{$line-height-100}",
        "fontSize": "{$font-size-100}",
        "letterSpacing": "{$letter-spacing-default}"
      },
      "type": "typography"
    },
    "$typography-body-medium-link": {
      "value": {
        "fontFamily": "{$font-family-default}",
        "fontWeight": "{$font-weight-semibold}",
        "lineHeight": "{$line-height-100}",
        "fontSize": "{$font-size-100}",
        "letterSpacing": "{$letter-spacing-default}",
        "textDecoration": "{$text-decoration-link}"
      },
      "type": "typography"
    },
    "$typography-body-small-low-emphasis": {
      "value": {
        "fontFamily": "{$font-family-default}",
        "fontWeight": "{$font-weight-regular}",
        "lineHeight": "{$line-height-75}",
        "fontSize": "{$font-size-75}",
        "letterSpacing": "{$letter-spacing-spacious}"
      },
      "type": "typography"
    },
    "$typography-body-small-high-emphasis": {
      "value": {
        "fontFamily": "{$font-family-default}",
        "fontWeight": "{$font-weight-semibold}",
        "lineHeight": "{$line-height-75}",
        "fontSize": "{$font-size-75}",
        "letterSpacing": "{$letter-spacing-spacious}"
      },
      "type": "typography"
    },
    "$typography-body-small-link": {
      "value": {
        "fontFamily": "{$font-family-default}",
        "fontWeight": "{$font-weight-semibold}",
        "lineHeight": "{$line-height-75}",
        "fontSize": "{$font-size-75}",
        "letterSpacing": "{$letter-spacing-spacious}",
        "textDecoration": "{$text-decoration-link}"
      },
      "type": "typography"
    },
    "$typography-body-tiny-low-emphasis": {
      "value": {
        "fontFamily": "{$font-family-default}",
        "fontWeight": "{$font-weight-regular}",
        "lineHeight": "{$line-height-50}",
        "fontSize": "{$font-size-50}",
        "letterSpacing": "{$letter-spacing-x-spacious}"
      },
      "type": "typography"
    },
    "$typography-body-tiny-link": {
      "value": {
        "fontFamily": "{$font-family-default}",
        "fontWeight": "{$font-weight-semibold}",
        "lineHeight": "{$line-height-50}",
        "fontSize": "{$font-size-50}",
        "letterSpacing": "{$letter-spacing-x-spacious}",
        "textDecoration": "{$text-decoration-link}"
      },
      "type": "typography"
    },
    "$color-background-neutral-primary": {
      "value": "#FFFFFF",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-background-neutral-secondary": {
      "value": "#F6F6F6",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-background-neutral-tertiary": {
      "value": "#EDEDEE",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-background-neutral-quaternary": {
      "value": "#DCDCDE",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-background-neutral-primary-inverse": {
      "value": "#101012",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-background-neutral-secondary-inverse": {
      "value": "#28292D",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-text-neutral-high-emphasis": {
      "value": "#28292D",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-text-neutral-medium-emphasis": {
      "value": "#34353A",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-text-neutral-low-emphasis": {
      "value": "#73757A",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-text-neutral-high-emphasis-inverse": {
      "value": "#FFFFFF",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-text-neutral-medium-emphasis-inverse": {
      "value": "#F6F6F6",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-text-neutral-low-emphasis-inverse": {
      "value": "#B9BABD",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-border-neutral-primary": {
      "value": "#FFFFFF",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-border-neutral-secondary": {
      "value": "#EDEDEE",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-border-neutral-tertiary": {
      "value": "#DCDCDE",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-border-neutral-quaternary": {
      "value": "#B9BABD",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-border-neutral-quinary": {
      "value": "#505259",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-background-cta": {
      "value": "#09733E",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-background-brand-primary": {
      "value": "#09733E",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-background-brand-secondary": {
      "value": "#0B8C4C",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-background-brand-tertiary": {
      "value": "#37A16C",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-background-brand-quaternary": {
      "value": "#BBDFCD",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-background-brand-quinary": {
      "value": "#E7F4ED",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-text-brand-primary": {
      "value": "#09733E",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-text-brand-secondary": {
      "value": "#0B8C4C",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-border-brand-primary": {
      "value": "#63B58C",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-border-brand-secondary": {
      "value": "#0B8C4C",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-border-brand-tertiary": {
      "value": "#09733E",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-background-info-primary": {
      "value": "#E9F1FB",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-background-info-secondary": {
      "value": "#2562BD",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-text-info": {
      "value": "#2B73DE",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-background-accent-primary": {
      "value": "#F5F2F8",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-background-accent-secondary": {
      "value": "#755891",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-text-accent": {
      "value": "#8A68AB",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-background-caution-primary": {
      "value": "#FEF4DA",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-background-danger-primary": {
      "value": "#FCE9E8",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-background-danger-secondary": {
      "value": "#E7554A",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-text-danger": {
      "value": "#E12B1D",
      "type": "color"
    },
    "$color-border-danger": {
      "value": "#E12B1D",
      "type": "color"
    }
  },
  "component": {
    "$shadow-page-header": {
      "value": {
        "x": "0",
        "y": "2px",
        "blur": "8px",
        "spread": "0",
        "color": "rgba(16,16,18,0.08)",
        "type": "dropShadow"
      },
      "type": "boxShadow"
    },
    "$page-footer-shadow": {
      "value": {
        "x": "0",
        "y": "-2px",
        "blur": "8px",
        "spread": "0",
        "color": "rgba(16,16,18,0.08)",
        "type": "dropShadow"
      },
      "type": "boxShadow"
    },
    "$button-hover-shadow": {
      "value": {
        "x": "0",
        "y": "4px",
        "blur": "12px",
        "spread": "4px",
        "color": "rgba(16,16,18,0.08)",
        "type": "dropShadow"
      },
      "type": "boxShadow"
    },
    "$button-pressed-shadow": {
      "value": [
        {
          "x": "0",
          "y": "2px",
          "blur": "6px",
          "spread": "0",
          "color": "rgba(16,16,18,0.24)",
          "type": "innerShadow"
        },
        {
          "x": "0",
          "y": "-2px",
          "blur": "6px",
          "spread": "0",
          "color": "rgba(16,16,18,0.24)",
          "type": "innerShadow"
        }
      ],
      "type": "boxShadow"
    }
  },
  "$themes": [],
  "$metadata": {
    "tokenSetOrder": [
      "universal",
      "semantic",
      "component"
    ]
  }
}
```

Generated output file (for android):

```
// Do not edit directly
// Generated on Thu, 09 Mar 2023 04:40:19 GMT


package StyleDictionaryColor;


import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.*

object StyleDictionaryColor {
    val universalColorGrey100 = #ededee
    val universalColorGrey200 = #dcdcde
    val universalColorGrey300 = #b9babd
    val universalColorGrey400 = #73757a
    val universalColorGrey50 = #F6F6F6
    val universalColorGrey500 = #505259
    val universalColorGrey600 = #44464C
    val universalColorGrey700 = #34353A
    val universalColorGrey800 = #28292D
    val universalColorGrey900 = #101012
    val universalColorOrange100 = #fdf2e5
    val universalColorOrange200 = #fce7cc
    val universalColorOrange300 = #face99
    val universalColorOrange400 = #f59d33
    val universalColorOrange500 = #f28500
    val universalColorOrange600 = #da7800
    val universalColorOrange700 = #c26a00
    val universalColorOrange800 = #9d5600
    val universalColorOrange900 = #613500
    val universalColorPrimary100 = #bbdfcd
    val universalColorPrimary200 = #8fcaad
    val universalColorPrimary300 = #63b58c
    val universalColorPrimary400 = #37a16c
    val universalColorPrimary50 = #e7f4ed
    val universalColorPrimary500 = #0b8c4c
    val universalColorPrimary600 = #09733e
    val universalColorPrimary700 = #075a31
    val universalColorPrimary800 = #054023
    val universalColorPrimary900 = #032715
    val universalColorRed100 = #fce9e8
    val universalColorRed200 = #f9d5d2
    val universalColorRed300 = #f3aaa5
    val universalColorRed400 = #e7554a
    val universalColorRed500 = #e12b1d
    val universalColorRed600 = #b42217
    val universalColorRed700 = #9e1e14
    val universalColorRed800 = #871a11
    val universalColorRed900 = #71160f
}
```

Comment: Could you paste the code here, it is very annoying to head in google drive to view the content of your files. JSON input file and output file can have reduced amount of data. I would also highlight what you expect in the generated file and what is happening wrong.

Comment: could not add directly due to character limit is there any other way that i could share which s helpful way?

Comment: that´s why I said to include for JSON and GENERATED file just a little part of the whole, just to see the error.

Comment: added both input design token JSON file and auto-generated kotlin file

Comment: I improved a bit the question. I removed the complementary colors to save some space. Now the missing part is to highlight what you are expecting in output and what is wrong. Then the question starts to be acceptable.